# What is the measurement of 1 cup?

Tags: measurements

[This recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/easy-oatmeal-muffins/) requires 1 cup milk and 1 cup oats.

***What is the measurement of 1 cup in milliliters?***

Comment: @Aaronut Thanks for the helpful other question link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A US cup is 237 mL.

It is more practical to use grams though:
   256 grams of milk and 156 grams of oats.

WolframAlpha is the perfect place to look up these kind of things:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+cup+of+oats

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+cup+of+milk

Comment: I just have have the ml measuring vessel, not the grams one, so what should I assume w.r.t ml for both of them?

Comment: 237 mL for both.

Comment: I seldom get in trouble using 250 ml as the conversion factor. It's wrong by a bit, but when a recipe calls for a cup of this and a cup of that, the ratio ends up correct. It's also easier to remember, and measure using metric cookware.

Comment: We Americans still haven't learned to cook by weight, for the most part.

Comment: @keshlam When a Carrington event takes out every electronic scale in Europe, they will be sorry. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_storm_of_1859